# flexible array of structure static declaration at given address not working?

Tags: c, embedded

```c
typedef struct {
uint64_t register;
uint32_t size;
} element_t;

typedef struct {
uint64_t idx;
element_t element[]; // Flexible array
} frame_t
```

I want to declare statically at defined memory location which i have reserved for this structure

```c
frame_t *frame = (frame_t *) 0xdeadbeef; /* this is the predefined memory location */
*frame = {
{.idx = 0x1;
 .element = {
   [0] = {
     .register = 0xdad;
     .size = 0x10;
   },
   [1] = { .register =0xcad;
     .size = 0x20;
   }
 }
},
{ .idx = 0x2;
  .element = {    
   [0] = { 
     .register = 0xdead;
     .size = 0x10;
   }
}
}
};
```

why is not the above static declaration of flexible array not working what is the correct way to declare this structure.

Comment: You can't use the keyword `register` as the name of a structure member — at least, not in standard C.

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of structs with flexible array members? Can't do that. Each such struct instance has it's own individual size that must be provided for by the programmer. Arrays require each element of identical size. They don't mix. If you manage to force it, compiler will use the raw struct size (without the flexible member) as array element size and all address calculations (except for the first element) will be wrong.

Comment: you can't declare array of structs with flexible array member ! Any alternative where i can represent the data in similar way

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  You should be creating a compound literal, which would look like a cast in front of the initializer.  See [6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5).

Comment: You can use an array of pointers to structures with a FAM. The pointers are all the same size.  But you are fighting against the “natural” behaviour of C.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems here

1. You can't have arrays of structs containing flexible memory arrays.
2. Assigning structs with flexible array members does not copy this member.
3. You can't assign the same way as during the initialization. You need to use compound literals for that. But it will not copy the flexible array either.

Answer (score 1):

The C specifications have little to say about flexible array members.  This is the entirety of C17's normative provisions specific to them:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
> named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
> *flexible array member*. **In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
> flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more
> trailing padding than the omission would imply.** However, when a `.`
> (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is (a pointer to) a
> structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names
> that member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the
> longest array (with the same element type) that would not make the
> structure larger than the object being accessed; the offset of the
> array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this
> would differ from that of the replacement array. If this array would
> have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior
> is undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to
> generate a pointer one past it.

(C17 6.7.21.1/18; emphasis added)

From this in particular, with the rest of the spec as context, we can conclude that

- Flexible array members are "flexible" in the sense that different instances of the host structure can have FAMs with different numbers of elements, but that does not change the fact that the number of elements in a given C array, including a FAM, never changes.
- The number of elements in a given FAM is determined by the size of the object containing it, not the other way around.

  It follows that the only way to get an object with a FAM having any elements is to *dynamically allocate* an object large enough to accommodate the structure itself plus the number of FAM elements wanted, or to obtain such an object by means outside the language spec.  Automatic and static allocation do not serve, because they provide only for the size of the structure, which does not include any provision for FAM elements.
- A FAM belonging to an array element does not have any members, except possibly if the element is the array's last.  This follows from the fact that the size of a structure ignores any FAM.
- Assignment and initialization are among the "most situations" in which FAMs are ignored.
- The only situation in which you can rely on interacting with a FAM is where you do so via the direct or indirect member-access operators (`.` and `->`).

So,

> I want to declare statically at defined memory location which i have reserved for this structure

The language spec does not provide for assigning static memory locations as you are trying to do, but it is possible that your implementation supports it.  Let's suppose it does.

You could then write *one* structure in that location, but not an array of them if any of them but the last need to have FAM members.

But why do you need a FAM?  You cannot change FAM sizes after allocation any more than you can change the size of other arrays, so if you were expecting to do that then you need an altogether different approach.  On the other hand, if you were not relying on that then you already know how many elements you need, so you can use an ordinary array providing the maximum number of elements needed:

```
#define MAX_ELEMENTS 2

// ...

typedef struct {
uint64_t idx;
element_t element[MAX_ELEMENTS]; // Flexible array
} frame_t

// ...

void f() {
    frame_t *frame = (frame_t *) 0xdeadbeef;

    *frame = (frame_t) {
        .idx = 0x1,
        .element = {
            [0] = { .register = 0xdad, .size = 0x10 },
            [1] = { .register = 0xcad, .size = 0x20 }
        }
    };

    *(frame + 1) = (frame_t) {
        .idx = 0x2;
        .element = {    
            [0] = { .register = 0xdead, .size = 0x10 }
        }
    };
}
```

Note also the details of compound literal syntax.